# If jQuery cookie index of

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

First, I found many topics on Google, but none of those solved my problem. I couldn't find a right solution to those topics.

Using **[jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)** plugin and trying to make a bookmark system, I store each item id in a cookie like this:

```
$('.bookmarkAds').click(function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  if ($(this).hasClass('RedHeart')) {
    $(this).removeClass('RedHeart');
    $.removeCookie('Bookmark_' + id, id);
    $(this).attr('title', 'Add');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('RedHeart');
    $.cookie('Bookmark_' + id, id, { expires: 3650 });
    $(this).attr('title', 'Remove');
  }
});
```

For example, these are user cookies:

```
Name: Bookmark_3017403 => Content: 3017403
Name: Bookmark_3217302 => Content: 3217302
Name: Bookmark_3217302 => Content: 2217312
```

Now I want to show bookmarked items in a page, want to get all cookies that contains `Bookmark_`, but I couldn't find the right solution. I tried:

```
if ($.cookie().indexOf('Bookmark_') > 1) {
}
```

or

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('Bookmark_') == -1) {
    alert("1");
} else {
    alert("2");
}
```

but no success.

**Goal:** get all cookies that index of `Bookmark_`. Is it possible? Or did I do something wrong? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to loop over all the cookies set on the page and check them individually. Also note that when checking with `indexOf` a value of `-1` means not found. `0` is a valid response that means the match was at the beginning of the string. Try this:

```
$.each($.cookie(), function(k, v) {
  if (k.indexOf('Bookmark_') != -1) {
    console.log(k, v);
  }
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/k07m5ksk/)

Note that I had to use jsFiddle for this example, as SO restricts cookie access in the snippets.